# How to display XML in HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a string with XML:

```
$string = 
"
<shoes>
    <shoe>
       <shouename>Shoue</shouename>
    </shoe>
</shoes>
";
```

And would like display it on my website like this:

```
This is XML string content:
<shoes>
    <shoe>
       <shouename>Shoue</shouename>
    </shoe>
</shoes>
```

So I would like to do it:

- on site, not in textbox
- without external libraries, frameworks etc.
- formatted with proper new lines
- formatted with tabs
- without colors etc., only text

So how to do it in plain and simple way?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you just want a plain-text representation of your (pre-formatted) string, you can wrap it in HTML `<pre/>` tags and use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) to escape the angle brackets:

```
<?PHP echo '<pre>', htmlentities($string), '</pre>'; ?>
```

Comment: @anto.nishanth firstly `echo` is a language construct so it don't need to be represented as function. Then here Chris use multiple parameter construct and you are talking about concatenation in to a single parameter. Please read documentation for further details http://php.net/echo.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `htmlentities()`, `htmlspecialchars()` or some similar function.

Answer (score 6):

It should work like that:

```
echo '<p>This is XML string content:</p>'
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a SimpleXMLobject

```
<pre>
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($obj,true));
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a solution to have slightly coloured output:

```
$escaped = htmlentities($content);
$formatted = str_replace('&lt;', '<span style="color:blue">&lt;', $escaped);
$formatted = str_replace('&gt;', '&gt;</span>', $formatted);
echo "<pre>$formatted</pre>\n";
```