# Send XML over TCP connection - only the data is being sent

Tags: c#, php, xml, tcp

Trying to send data using C# over a TCP connection.

```
string reply = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root><ele1 type='2'/><author>patrick</author>
<address>spain</address></root>";
```

Here is where I think the problem is:

```
reply = format.ProcessMessage(message); - this method returns the above string
byte[] breply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply);
stream.Write(breply, 0, breply.Length);
```

The response on the client's end is: patrickspain
But I want the entire XML string to be sent. Anyone has any idea of how to fix this?

The following is my PHP client code:

```
<?php

$host    = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = 7890;
$message = "Test Message";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data\n");
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  : ".$result;
socket_close($socket);

?>
```

Comment: My guess is that all data is being sent, but your client (or the tool you use to view the response) is stripping out the Xml elements. Can you check the _number_ of bytes received at the client?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. The client is a simple test application coded in PHP which is simply printing out the response from C# in the browser

Comment: I just realised that problem isnt with C#, but I suspect PHP the client has been stripping out my XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser receives your data just fine. It's trying to show XML as HTML, which means you'll just see the inner text of each node, in this case the author's name.

Right-click the page and click "View Source" to see what the browser received. You can also use a tool like Fiddler to debug HTTP traffic.

Comment: Programming has a way of making me feel dumb sometimes. Thanks, it was working fine all along

Comment: @D.Rattansingh we've all been there. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864303/how-to-display-xml-in-html-in-php.