# How convert CDATA xml with more single and double quote in a string php?

Tags: php, xml, cdata

Sorry for stupid question...

i have in file xml a `CDATA` in children node:

```
  <placemark>
   <description><![CDATA[ <h2>ML 2.1 - GREATER LOS ANGELES' AREA, CALIF.</h2><br><b>2016-09-29   16:10:00.3 UTC</b><br /><br /><table style="width:100%;"><tr><td><b>Latitude</b></td><td style="padding-left:5px;">  34.13 N<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>Longitude</b></td><td style="padding-left:5px;">  119.14 W<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>Deph</b></td><td style="padding-left:5px;">  20   Km<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>Magnitude</b></td><td style="padding-left:5px;">  ML 2.1<br></td></tr></table><br /><br /><a href="http://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/earthquake.php?id=534164"> Link to the event </a> ]]></description>
  </placemark>
```

I get CDATA but i don't know how coonvert it in string php

How can add for`'` used in CDATA backslash escape `\` ?
In this way than is easy...just write

```
  $file= simplexml_load_file(FILE);
  $CDATA = $file -> placemark -> description;
  $string= "'".$CDATA."'"
```

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english, thanks a lot in advice !

Comment: What is `$CDATA`? What did you use to parse the XML? Please post [minimal but complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of the code that you use to get the `CDATA` from the XML..

Comment: @har07 i edit the question explaining what is $CDATA .... but the question is how covert it in string if inside are many single and double quote

Comment: Alright now its clear what `$CDATA` is. Next, what's the problem with your current code? How do you think `'` within the CDATA caused any problem?

Comment: @har07 try yourself... print $string and will notice that is not a string. Same result if add double quote at start and end of $CDATA. Problem is that are many single and double quote..

Comment: That's why we need [MCVE], so that we can try it... like [this one](https://eval.in/757109). But as you can see in the linked demo, the result is string. How did you come to conclusion that yours wasn't string?

Comment: Sorry @har07 i don't understand... i know javascript better than php and i know that a correct string is ' text ' not  ' text ' '.  I'm sorry for my english but maybe i can explain what i think with this example in javascript https://jsfiddle.net/5cfgk8ra/

Comment: @har07 the problem is that single quote after LOS ANGELES. If there was not i could add single quote at start and end of $CDATA

Comment: Your JS did quite a different thing. You tried to create a string from literal string there, while in your PHP there is no literal string involved. I guess you tried to display the `$CDATA` and can't see it in the rendered HTML page? If that is the case, see : [How to display XML in HTML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864303/how-to-display-xml-in-html-in-php)

Comment: so it is a string also if it is not a literal string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literals are how you write values in source code. In `$foo = "abc";` the `"abc"` is the string literal.

The `$file->placemark->description` is an instance of `SimpleXMLElement` and can be cast into a string.

Here is an example for an explicit cast:
`$string = (string)$file->placemark->description;`

But it can be implicit, like using it in a string context:
`echo $file->placemark->description;`

I am not sure why you're trying to add quotes to it. If you try to output the string to JavaScript, you should try `json_encode()`.